# debugging with ansible: How to get stderr and stdout from failing commands to be printed respecting newlines so as to be human readable?

Tags: ansible

If I run a simple ansible playbook, I often get difficult-to-read output from failing tasks, like that below.  Big problems:

- the linebreaks within the stdout are printed as \n, not an actual linebreak.  This makes things like python tracebacks very obnoxious to read.
- stdout, stderr, cmd... the json blob being output contains lots of useful things, but since they are all run together on the same line it is
  very difficult for a human to parse.

**How can I get ansible to print its output in a format that I can read easily, so I can debug?**

Here is the yucky output:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbooks/backUpWebsite.yml

PLAY [localhost] 
***************************************************************

TASK [command] 
*****************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "python -c 'ksjfasdlkjf'", "delta": "0:00:00.037459", "end": "2017-10-03 19:58:50.525257", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-10-03 19:58:50.487798", "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>\nNameError: name 'ksjfasdlkjf' is not defined", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
        to retry, use: --limit @<snip>playbooks/backUpWebsite.retry

PLAY RECAP 
*********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0 failed=1
```

Here is the script that generated it:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
      #wrong on purpose!
    - shell: "python -c 'ksjfasdlkjf'"
      register: unobtainable
```

Answer (score 8):

To get ansible to respect linebreaks in output so that you can read the stdout of your failing task, **change the stdout_callback to minimal.**

In your ansible.cfg, change the stdout_callback option:

```
stdout_callback=minimal
```

the 'minimal' output is a bit terse, but it prints output respecting linebreaks so that you can see what is happening:

```
 $ ansible-playbook playbooks/backUpWebsite.yml
 localhost | FAILED | rc=1 >>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'ksjfasdlkjf' is not defined

         to retry, use: --limit @<snip>/playbooks/backUpWebsite.retry
```

**Other things that I hear can work**

- You could write your own callback handler for stdout.  [People have done this](http://blog.cliffano.com/2014/04/06/human-readable-ansible-playbook-log-output-using-callback-plugin/) and it seems straightforward to do, but I've never tried it.

**Things I tried that don't work:**

**Three vs**.  Use "ansible-playbook  -vvv".  You get a tremendous pile of output, which does include the json nicely linebroken, but the newlines within the stdout output are not printed, so stdout/stderr are still hard to read:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbooks/backUpWebsite.yml -vvv
Using <snip>/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAYBOOK: backUpWebsite.yml ****************************************************
1 plays in playbooks/backUpWebsite.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
task path: <snip>/playbooks/backUpWebsite.yml:6
Using module file <snip>/ansible/lib/ansible/modules/core/commands/command.py
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: <snip>
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo <snip>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507083519.4247632-54588405727205 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1507083519.4247632-54588405727205="` echo <snip>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507083519.4247632-54588405727205 `" ) && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpumtlourx TO <snip>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507083519.4247632-54588405727205/command.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x <snip>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507083519.4247632-54588405727205/ <snip>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507083519.4247632-54588405727205/command.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '<snip>/anaconda3/bin/python <snip>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507083519.4247632-54588405727205/command.py; rm -rf "<snip>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507083519.4247632-54588405727205/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "python -c 'ksjfasdlkjf'",
    "delta": "0:00:00.037657",
    "end": "2017-10-03 20:18:39.843933",
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "python -c 'ksjfasdlkjf'",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "warn": true
        },
        "module_name": "command"
    },
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2017-10-03 20:18:39.806276",
    "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>\nNameError: name 'ksjfasdlkjf' is not defined",
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": [],
    "warnings": []
}
        to retry, use: --limit @<snip>/sys/ansible_readynet/playbooks/backUpWebsite.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

**Credit**

[I posted this issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27078) against ansible on github in hope of persuading people that the ansible defaults are very unhelpful.  jhawkesworth helpfully introduced me to the 'minimal' stdout callback.

I have since found [this page in the ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/callback.html) that mentions this plugin in a very non-prominent way.

IMHO, this secret of getting readable error output from ansible is entirely too well hidden from new users, and I have personally witnessed this sour several people I know on the use of ansible in general.

Comment: `stdout_callback=debug` seems like a decent option as well (minimal doesn't show which task is busy).